# handling tie breakers with heapq in python

Tags: python, sorting, heapq

I have this array

```
values = [("aaa", 10), ("bbb", 10), ("ccc", 10), ("David", 15)]
```

I want to add these to a priorityqueue. For each value, I want to sort by value[1] (the number) then if its a tie (e.g `("aaa", 10), ("bbb", 10)`), I want to sort lexigraphically by value[0] (the string)

I have tried doing this

```
def compareValAndName(a, b):
    if a[1] == b[1]:
        if a[0] < b[0]:
            return 1
        else:
            return -1
    return a[1] - b[1]
    
n_largest = heapq.nlargest(5, values, key=cmp_to_key(compareValAndName))
```

However, I don't want to use largest since I will be popping and pushing into my queue consistantly

Comment: `key=lambda p: (p[1], p[0])`? I think you misunderstood the key-function

Comment: Any reason you can't swap the order of the of the entries you're adding to the queue so that the default order does what you want?

Comment: Also, FWIW you can use `operator.itemgetter(1, 0)` in place of `lambda p: (p[1], p[0])` for better performance.

Comment: *"I don't want to use largest"* - You mean `nlargest`? What **do** you want to use?